# System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая попытка чтения при отсутствии данных."

Tags: c#, winforms

Понимаю что в reader нет данных, но не могу найти ошибку. К БД точно подключен, Название таблицы и имена полей точно правильные. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM [Autorization] WHERE [Логин]='"+Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text)+"'", myConnection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        string login = Convert.ToString(reader["Логин"]);
        string password = Convert.ToString(reader["Пароль"]);
        string permission = Convert.ToString(reader["Права"]);
```

Comment: Нужно reader.read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!